# Different language for producer / consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I was wondering if it's possible to use different languages for producer and consumer via AMQP and RabbitMQ?

For example: Java for the producer and python/php for consumer, or vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, AMQP is language agnostic meaning that as long as you have clients that can connect to the **same** RabbitMQ server you should be able to communicate between them. [Luckily there are already RabbitMQ clients available written in many languages including Java, Python and PHP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. but the question is that how it's possible to cast an object "produced" from a language like java to an object "consumed" by a language like php ?!? (what about the special types in  some languages, etc ... ); and whether I should  use a serializer/deserializer for that ?

Comment: @nima you didn't mention that you wanted to send different objects in your question only that you wanted different languages connecting to the queues.  This specificity is required. You cannot serialized a Java object and expect that to be understood by another language.  The only simple way to make this work is with strings.  However there are many serialization techniques that allow you to send an object as a string and have it read by many other languages.  Look at JSON, XML and YAML.

Comment: @robthewolf thanks buddy for your reply. as you mentioned I want to send(produce) an object with a language (like python) and receive it (consume) with another language (like java); so what I'm asking is that how it's possible ? I know json (and probably other serializers) is being used in rabbitmq, but I'm not sure if it's possible to use it in this way

Comment: @nima it is possible.  Assuming you understand how to create and connect to queues and exchanges, all you need to do is convert the object to a JSON string and send the string as a byte array.  On the consumer side you will convert the byte array to a string then use JSON to convert it to a java object.  Make sure that you can create equivalent objects on both sides

Comment: @robthewolf thanks again for your reply. it's a bit weird ... I implemented a simple producer/consumer system in java, using json as the serializer and everything was fine; I can do the same in php; but the object sent by php as producer, cannot be handled in java (as consumer) and fails with a MessageConversionException (failed to convert Message content. Could not resolve... in header). I think I do something wrong while encoding the object within the producer. any clue ? P.S: I'm using json_encode as the encoding method and setting the 'content_type' to 'application/json'. thanks in advance

Comment: I think I found the problem. I was using spring-amqp along with the project's JsonMessageConverter for decoding the json-encoded message in consumer which seems to use a class called DefaultClassMapper that searches for something called "__TypeId__" in the header of the message. poor documentation ! I think I just have to write a CustomCalssMapper to ignore that constant. thanks all by the way :)

Comment: yep. As I said, I've created a new CustomCalssMapper which ignores the useless TypeId in the header and used it as the CalssMapper of the spring's JsonMessageConverter :) again, thank you and RobotEyes for your support.