# Can Laravel RabbitMQ consume message from another programming language?

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I have read this post [Different language for producer / consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917199/different-language-for-producer-consumer), they say it's possible to consume messages from producers even though the producers are in different programming languages, but how to implement that thing using laravel. For example i have a producer using nodejs and laravel as a consumer, i use [laravel-queue-rabbitmq](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) as driver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have different languages for producer / consummer. It's one of the main purpose of using Rabbitmq to communicate asynchronously between services.

You can find example if both Node.js and PHP on the [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).

If you prefer to use a Laravel library instead, it's fine too. Just read and follow README instructions provided.

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend on the previous answer. While the message can be created by any producer (written in any language), the laravel queue writes a specific payload into the message body, like

```
{
"uuid": "d3bb48e4-cd10-42bc-90e3-8b80c381a342",
"displayName": "App\\Jobs\\UpdateSearchTableJob",
"job": "Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
"maxTries": null,
"maxExceptions": null,
"failOnTimeout": false,
"backoff": null,
"timeout": null,
"retryUntil": null,
"data": {
    "commandName": "App\\Jobs\\UpdateSearchTableJob",
    "command": "O:29:\"App\\Jobs\\UpdateSearchTableJob\":1:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000data\";a:2:{s:10:\"type\";s:5:\"user\";s:2:\"id\";s:3:\"123\";}}"
},
"id": "02f7d3f2-9234-4d6c-97f4-01c301774560"
```

}

This payload is specific to Laravel jobs.
So if you want to consume this job in a Laravel application, you would need to reverse-engineer this payload in your (non-Laravel/non-PHP) application that produces the event.